# Advice with CTC (Fresher)

Tags: india, salary

What would be the in-hand salary for the CTC 8.4 lakhs (breakup attached in link)? Are they just ballooning up the figure? What would be some reasonable points to discuss with them before I accept this offer?

[image: CTC breakdown]

Answer (score 1):

Gross is 6,46,404 less of your pf contribution and professional tax. Income would be around Rs 6,25,000 and taxes would be Rs 26,000.

Monthly tax home around Rs 49,100.

Most companies show up items to make a feel good factor.

Is it good offer is opinion based